# NullpointerException / InvocationtargetException Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

I am trying to build a timetable app for an assignment using android. I keep getting a Null pointer exception as well as an invocation target exception. I realise a nullpointerexception is usually caused when a variable has not been initializied properly, but I can't see where I am going wrong in my code.

The fields are filled in an xml file, the user clicks the save button and the "addNewModule" method is called below. The error is generated in the "queryValuesMap.put("ModuleCode", ModuleCode.getText().toString())" line. I have added a  piece of my DBTools file in case it may be relevant.

NewModule.java

```
package com.example.mycoursetimetable;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


 public class NewModule extends Activity{

// The EditText objects

EditText ModuleCode;
EditText ModuleName;
EditText ModuleType;
EditText DayOfWeek;
EditText StartTime;
EditText EndTime;
EditText Location;
EditText AdditionalInfo;

DBTools dbTools;

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dbTools = new DBTools(this);

    // Get saved data if there is any

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Designate that add_module.xml is the interface used

    setContentView(R.layout.add_module);

    // Initialize the EditText objects
    ModuleCode= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modcodeet);
    ModuleName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.modnameet);
    ModuleType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.moduletypeet);
    DayOfWeek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dowet);
    StartTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.starttimeet);
    EndTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endtimeet);
    Location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationet);
    AdditionalInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.additionalinfoet);

 }
 public void addNewModule(View view) {


    // Will hold the HashMap of values 

    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap =  new  HashMap<String, String>();

    // Get the values from the EditText boxes

    queryValuesMap.put("ModuleCode", ModuleCode.getText().toString());// This si where error occurs
    queryValuesMap.put("ModuleName", ModuleName.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("ModuleType", ModuleType.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("DayOfWeek", DayOfWeek.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("StartTime", StartTime.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("EndTime", EndTime.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("Location", Location.getText().toString());
    queryValuesMap.put("AdditionalInfo", AdditionalInfo.getText().toString());

    // Call for the HashMap to be added to the database

    dbTools.insertModule(queryValuesMap);

    // Call for MainActivity to execute

    this.callMainActivity(view);


}
public void callMainActivity(View view) {
    Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(theIntent);
}   
}
```

DBTools.java

```
package com.example.mycoursetimetable;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBTools extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBTools(Context applicationContext){

    super(applicationContext, "module.db", null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE modules ( ModuleCode TEXT PRIMARY KEY, ModuleName TEXT,ModuleType TEXT, DayOfWeek TEXT, StartTime TEXT, EndTime TEXT,Location TEXT,AdditionalInfo Text)";

    database.execSQL(query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS modules";

    database.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(database);

 }

 public void insertModule(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("ModuleCode", queryValues.get("ModuleCode"));
    values.put("ModuleName", queryValues.get("ModuleName"));
    values.put("ModuleType", queryValues.get("ModuleType"));
    values.put("DayOfWeek", queryValues.get("DayOfWeek"));
    values.put("StartTime", queryValues.get("StartTime"));
    values.put("EndTime", queryValues.get("EndTime"));
    values.put("Location", queryValues.get("Location"));
    values.put("AdditionalInfo", queryValues.get("AdditionalInfo"));

    database.insert("modules", null, values);

    database.close();

 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mycoursetimetable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// The Intent is used to issue that an operation should
// be performed

Intent intent;
TextView ModuleCode;

// The object that allows me to manipulate the database

DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);

// Called when the Activity is first called

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get saved data if there is any

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Designate that edit_module.xml is the interface used
    // is activity_main.xml

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Gets all the data from the database and stores it
    // in an ArrayList

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> moduleList =  dbTools.getAllModules();

    // Check to make sure there are contacts to display

    if(moduleList.size()!=0) {

        // Get the ListView and assign an event handler to it

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                // When an item is clicked get the TextView
                // with a matching checkId

                ModuleCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleCode);

                // Convert that ModuleId into a String

                String ModuleID = ModuleCode.getText().toString();  

                // Signals an intention to do something
                // getApplication() returns the application that owns
                // this activity

                Intent  theIndent = new Intent(getApplication(),EditModule.class);

                // Put additional data in for EditContact to use

                theIndent.putExtra("ModuleCode", ModuleID); 

                // Calls for EditModule

                startActivity(theIndent); 
            }
        }); 

        // A list adapter is used bridge between a ListView and
        // the ListViews data

        // The SimpleAdapter connects the data in an ArrayList
        // to the XML file

        // First we pass in a Context to provide information needed
        // about the application
        // The ArrayList of data is next followed by the xml resource
        // Then we have the names of the data in String format and
        // their specific resource ids

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(     MainActivity.this,moduleList, R.layout.module_entry, new String[] { "ModuleCode","ModuleName", "moduleType"}, new int[] {R.id.moduleCode, R.id.moduleName, R.id.ModuleType});

        // setListAdapter provides the Cursor for the ListView
        // The Cursor provides access to the database data

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

// When showAddContact is called with a click the Activity 
// NewModule is called

public void showAddModule(View view) {
    Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewModule.class);
    startActivity(theIntent);
}
}
```

add_module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/add_module"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modulecodetv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/module_code" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/modulecodeet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modulenametv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/module_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/modulenameet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >

    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moduletypetv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/module_type" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/moduletypeet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dowtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/dow" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dowet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/starttimetv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/start_time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/starttimeet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endtimetv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/end_time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/endtimeet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
    </EditText>
 </TableRow>

  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/location" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/locationet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/additionalinfotv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
        android:text="@string/additional_info" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/additionalinfoet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_5dp" >
    </EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addNewModule"
        android:text="@string/save_data" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Logcat

```
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): Caused by:     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     ... 11 more
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at  com.example.mycoursetimetable.NewModule.addNewModule(NewModule.java:78)
10-22 11:34:56.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     ... 14 more
10-22 11:34:56.438: D/dalvikvm(1765): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 454K, 14% free 3272K/3788K, paused 96ms, total 136ms
10-22 11:39:56.627: I/Process(1765): Sending signal. PID: 1765 SIG: 9
10-22 11:39:59.818: D/dalvikvm(1791): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 5% free 2938K/3080K, paused 146ms, total 159ms
10-22 11:39:59.818: I/Choreographer(1791): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:40:00.268: I/Choreographer(1791): Skipped 264 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:40:00.437: D/gralloc_goldfish(1791): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-22 11:40:01.157: I/Choreographer(1791): Skipped 193 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:11.667: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:11.867: D/dalvikvm(1835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 5% free 2937K/3080K, paused 99ms, total 108ms
10-22 11:46:12.187: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 324 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:12.287: D/gralloc_goldfish(1835): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-22 11:46:12.607: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:17.358: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:19.138: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:21.387: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:24.517: D/dalvikvm(1835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 247K, 9% free 3204K/3512K, paused 54ms, total 68ms
10-22 11:46:25.689: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:28.367: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 236 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:28.857: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:31.287: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:31.757: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:32.157: D/dalvikvm(1835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 445K, 14% free 3270K/3776K, paused 52ms, total 65ms
10-22 11:46:32.217: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:33.297: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:35.288: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:35.597: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:38.027: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:38.277: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:39.397: D/dalvikvm(1835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 505K, 15% free 3279K/3844K, paused 53ms, total 61ms
10-22 11:46:40.117: I/Choreographer(1835): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:42.928: D/AndroidRuntime(1835): Shutting down VM
10-22 11:46:43.027: W/dalvikvm(1835): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     ... 11 more
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     at com.example.mycoursetimetable.NewModule.addNewModule(NewModule.java:59)
10-22 11:46:43.358: E/AndroidRuntime(1835):     ... 14 more
10-22 11:46:49.328: I/Process(1835): Sending signal. PID: 1835 SIG: 9
10-22 11:46:52.637: I/Choreographer(1864): Skipped 131 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-22 11:46:52.707: D/gralloc_goldfish(1864): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-22 11:46:53.237: I/Choreographer(1864): Skipped 153 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: This sounds weird but can you try with `ModuleCode.getText() + ""` ?

Comment: Do you have a LogCat`

Comment: logcat up, as an aside if anyone knows an easy way to indent the logcat in a text document I'm all ears, I could then put up the full one(though i don't think it would be any use, these are the latest ones) I tried it with moduleCode.getText()+"", didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Not getting exactly the issue,but try this one.
create DBTool object after super statement in oncreate method, that may be the issue.
Super call should be the first.

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // Get saved data if there is any
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 dbTools = new DBTools(this);
```

like this, try

Comment: Tried it, no luck unfortunately:(

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, the button calls the method "addNewModule" found on the first file, using Onlick="addnewmodule", I can put the mainactivity file up but I think it could make the question more confusing.

Comment: not getting exactly what is issue, try removing 'this', like this call method  callMainActivity(view);